# post-receive git hook does not work from command line

Tags: git, bash, command-line, hook

I've created a web hook in git so that when I push to the bare git repo on my web server, the files are updated in the actual web directory.  These are the relevant lines in the post-receive file:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/srv/www/test1 git checkout -f
echo 'post-receive action complete' $(date) >> git_update_log
```

This works just fine when I do an actual push to the repo.  But when I try to execute it from the command line (via an ssh session), it doesn't work.  I've tried going into the hooks directory and typing './post-receive' or '. post-receive' and I've tried just running the command 'GIT_WORK_TREE=/srv/www/test1 git checkout -f' from within the hooks directory or from within the root of the bare git repo (where the hooks directory is located).  No dice.

I've even tried switching to /srv/www/test1 and running the command 'GIT_DIR=/home/my_username/test1.git GIT_WORK_TREE=/srv/www/test1 git checkout -f' - and that doesn't work either.

What am I missing here?  As far as I can tell, the post-receive file is just a bash script (it starts with #!/bin/sh), so why can't I get it to run from the command line?

If it's of any relevance, the version of Git on that server is 1.6.0.2.

---

**UPDATE - WITH ANSWER**

In response to my own question of, "What am I missing here?": I was missing a clear understanding of the workflow, and I was confusing `checkout` and `fetch`.

From the command line, things were working as they were supposed to be, but there were just no new files in the local repo to copy to the web directory; `chekcout -f` only copies files when there are new ones available (in the local repo) to copy.  So to get the new files into the local repo, this command worked: `git fetch git@remoterepo.com:my_username/test1.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master` (thanks to torek for that).

However, I found that fetch command (in this scenario) to be unreliable / unstable (apparently this is kind of a kludgy way of doing things), so I ended up taking torek's advice and setting up a fetch mirror.  I deleted the repo directory (test1.git) and recreated it as a mirror using `git clone --mirror git@remoterepo.com:my_username/test1.git`.  The command `git --git-dir=/home/my_username/test1.git remote update` works for getting any new files from the remote repo, and the command `git --git-dir=/home/my_username/test1.git --work-tree=/srv/www/test1 checkout -f` works for copying the newly available files to the web site folder.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is pretty wide open; what *does* happen when you run `GIT_... git checkout -f`?  Does it spit out error messages, or just hang, or...?  Also: 1.6.0.2, good grief, and I thought CentOS was behind! :-)

Comment: There is no error message or output of any kind.  I'm just returned to the command prompt as if the previous command ran successfully.  If I issue the 'echo $?' command, I get a response of 0 which indicates no errors from the previous command.  "Does not work" is pretty accurate...had I gotten an error message, I would've said something like,  "post-receive git hook issues the following error message when I run it from the command line: ..."  This is running on an older SuSE machine (a client's, not mine), so that's why the Git version is so old.

Comment: OK, that suggests that the `git checkout -f` is actually *succeeding*.  Probably the index shows that there is no work to be done (which would be unsurprising).  Remember that each repository, including a bare one (that would receive push requests), has just the one index/staging-area, and the one `HEAD`, and those two record the current commit and its cache state.  If the cache is out of sync with the (`$GIT_WORK_TREE`) target, Git may not notice and think it is *in* sync and do nothing.  An easy (albeit low quality) workaround is to `rm -rf` the target, forcing Git to notice.

Comment: Ok, I removed one of the files and ran the post-receive script from the command line, and it restored the file from the local repository.  Then I realized that I'm checking out from the local repository and not getting the updated files from the remote repo.  So I need to do a git pull first...but that generates an error: 'fatal: /usr/lib/git/git-pull cannot be used without a working tree.'

Even if I specify the working tree in the command line, I get the same error.  So how do I pull from the remote repo?  When the post-receive hook runs, it happens after a remote repo pushes to it.

Comment: Indeed, you don't want `git pull`.  At most you want `git fetch`, in some form.  But a post-receive hook normally runs, well, post receive: the receiving (bare) repository has just picked up any new commits and other objects, and has just had its branch and/or tag names updated (you should typically read stdin until EOF, to find the old and new SHA-1 hashes and each reference's full name).  If `refs/heads/master` is updated, someone pushed to `master`; if `refs/heads/develop` is updated, someone pushed to `develop`; if both are updated, someone pushed to both; and so on.

Comment: So I switched to the target web directory (the working tree) and tried this comand:

git --work-tree=/srv/www/test1/ --git-dir=/home/my_username/test1.git pull

But that generated this error:

fatal: 'origin': unable to chdir or not a git archive
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: Using `git fetch` here is Weird® because, again, as a bare repository with a post-receive deployment script, it's clear that the *idea* was to do development in a different git repository and then *push* to this one.  Using *fetch* is reversing the information flow.  It's not a crazy way to work things, and from some security model aspects, a polling model is nicer. But `git fetch` is not quite symmetric with `git push`, so if you *do* want to Reverse the Polarity of the Neutron Flow a la the Pertwee Doctor, you have to make additional settings-changes.

Comment: The one big settings-change (maybe temporary, command-line-only) would be that instead of the normal way that `git fetch` *renames* references, you want to simply *overwrite* references. For instance when bringing `refs/heads/master` from elsewhere, you want to *replace* the existing `refs/heads/master` with the new SHA-1 hash, willy-nilly. From the command line, `git fetch <remote> '+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'` will do that—but beware that this has no safety checks: no crash harnesses, no brakes, no roll cage, just "replace what I have with what I got from them".

Comment: Somewhat safer (allows only fast forward operations) is to fetch `refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`. This is what Git normally allows (without `--force`) when pushing, with the information flow in the more-expected direction. You can also fetch just one specific ref: `git fetch <remote> refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master` for instance. And, if this is to be a permanent thing, you can put the new refspecs in as the `fetch` setting for that particular remote, after which `git fetch <remote>` will do that.

Comment: I ran the command 'git fetch git@remoterepo.com:my_username/test1.git' and that seemed to successfully get the latest changes. But running the 'git checkout -f' command for the working tree did not produce any update in the working tree. What are the additional setting-changes that I need to make for successful polarity reversal? And it's not necessarily that I'm trying to reverse the post-receive action; I'm just trying to pull/fetch/get/git the latest updates from a remote repo and apply the changes to the web directory - from the command line, on the machine where the web directory resides.

Comment: Well, all these analogies are getting a bit silly, but: you're working on the bare metal, in a bare repo, engine exposed and dangerous actions everywhere, by doing it this way. It really was built to push-to; so why are you bypassing all the safeties and doing things this way in the first place? What's the real goal here?

Comment: Sweet - running `git fetch git@remoterepo.com:my_username/test1.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master` did the trick.  Now the command line post-receive script causes the working tree to be updated correctly.

Comment: I've set up a Git repo for some "developers" who are unfamiliar with Git (but desperately need it to avoid stepping on each others' toes)...they seem to be mostly design and graphics guys.  They had been uploading to their web server via FTP, but now they're pushing to a GitLab repo.  The idea is that when they push to GitLab, the GitLab server calls a webhook URL that will cause a push to the web server.  But the "push" is actually just a cgi-bin shell script on the web server that grabs the data from GitLab.  I realize this isn't the standard use for the webhook, but it's a start.

Comment: I recommended that the devs just push directly to the repo on their web server, but that would involve having them set up SSH keys, which is apparently too much to hope for.  The other option would be for me to set up https access, but it's an older server, with an older version of Git, and I'm not sure how much of a pain in the ass that would be.  So the command line / cgi-bin script option seemed like the easiest way to go.  Or am I just doing something stupid?

Comment: Ah, in that case it sounds like simply slaving this repo to the one on GitLab is the (or a) way to go.  Essentially you will turn this repo into a fetch mirror (still a bare repo, but no longer receiving any pushes at all).  As an alternative, you could set up the web server's `/srv/www/...` as a work-tree for a non-bare repo (with `.git` directly in there, or using env vars and/or `--git-dir` and/or `--git-work-tree` options). That has the advantage of being less weird / more standard, and hence probably more comprehensible, but it's a bigger change.

Comment: I'm not familiar with slaving a repo.  Google bring up gits / gitslave - is this what you're referring to?  What's the difference between using the web server's web directory as a non-bare repo and using a bare repo in a separate location?  I understand that the non-bare repo has the .git directory in it, along with the tracked files, but both methods seem to be effectively the same.  Based on what I've read, it seems that using a bare repo in a separate directory is the Right Way™ to do this (i.e. push git repo files to your web server).

Comment: One thing that may (or may not) complicate things is that the web directory has *lots* of files and folders that are not tracked in the repo.  I don't know if that would be affected by slaving or by making it a regular (non-bare) repo.  These guys have backup folders in their own web directory - to the tune of about 20 GB (don't blame me - I'm just the guy who got called in to try to improve things).

Comment: Wasn't referring to gits/gitslave; the proper technical term in Git-ese is "mirror".  The extra untracked files on the side *do* complicate things, as well.  A fetch mirror *will* work, and means you can do your deployment in several stages, which may be helpful here.  A fetch mirror is otherwise somewhat dead weight, mainly useful as a redistribution point (same reasoning as with FTP mirrors, for instance).

Comment: I think this problem is solved, right? Than maybe it would be great to udate the question from the many facts burried in the comments so others can profit from it more easily (and no one comes here and thinks this is an active question to be answered) ;-)